# How should I deal with outliers in multiple variables in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, outliers

I am kindof new to statistical programming, and I am currently working on a dataset of 110 000 observations of 19 variables in a credit default dataset, and want to create some models like logistic regression and rf where the dependent variable is whether or not a company defaulted or not. However, while most of the variables seem normally distributed, there are 3 variables whose boxplots don't even have boxes, and there are many extremely high outlier values. I tried to omit observations containing these outliers, but ended up with only 20 000 observations which I highly doubt is right. 
That is why I am wondering if there is a good way of dealing with such outliers, and how I can implement it in R? See below for one of the boxplots that illustrate my point:
[image: Extreme outliers]

Comment: have your tried taking the log of the variables in question?

Comment: What is the data set? Did you expect these variables to be normal? Why do you want to transform them to make them normal? If your filtered data set only ended up with ~18% of the data, that means that almost all of your data is an 'outlier' in some dimension - if that's the case I'd caution you against thinking of these as 'outliers' and instead consider them 'data'

Comment: "What to do with outliers" (or "are these outliers?", or perhaps, "what to do with skewed data?") is a statistics question, not a programming one - and one that depends a lot on your goals, what sort of model(s) you are using, and contextual knowledge about the data---that belongs on Cross Validated (stats.stackexchange). Once you know what you want to do, if you're having trouble doing it in R, that's when it becomes a programming question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Don't remove "outliers". Think about the distribution of these variables, and how to model these distributions.

Comment: it's a credit default data set, the variable I have as dependent is the binary variable for default, and the extreme values are for independent variables equity, total assets, and revenue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the Inter Quartile Range (IQR) and convert anything more or less than 1.5 times that to NA.

```
q_col <- quantile(df$col, probs= c(.25, .75), na.rm = T)
iqr_df <- IQR(df$col, na.rm = T)

df$col_new <- df$col
df$col_new[(df$col < q_col - 1.5*(iqr_df)) | (df$col > q_col + 1.5*(iqr_df))] <- NA
```

If a simple implementation of that does not work then try to carry out a log transform and then carry out the IQR steps above:

```
df$col <- log10(df$col)

(... repeat the steps above)
```